# Does a column have only dates or also datetimes in pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm trying to write a function to assess whether a column in a pandas DataFrame has only dates or also datetimes, in order to decide whether to create a date or timestamp column in an external database.

All dates in a DataFrame are stored as the same type, but date-only values would have no time component

Is there an efficient way of doing this? I wouldn't want to loop through each column in python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check to see if the `datetime` column is equal to its `date` component`

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Date=pd.to_datetime(
            ['2017-03-01',
             '2017-03-01 00:00:00',
             '2017-03-01 00:00:01',
             '2017-03-01 10:30:00'])))

df

                 Date
0 2017-03-01 00:00:00
1 2017-03-01 00:00:00
2 2017-03-01 00:00:01
3 2017-03-01 10:30:00
```

---

We can see that the first 2 rows don't require the time component but the last 2 do.  We can check it with

```
df.Date == pd.to_datetime(df.Date.dt.date)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

So we can check if the entire column needs the time component with

```
(d1.Date == pd.to_datetime(d1.Date.dt.date)).all()

False
```

In this case, `False` indicates we should use `datetime`